# Changes made to forge minecraft mod not appearing in test client

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm very new to the ways of Minecraft modding for forge 1.20.1, and I've been using the tutorial by Kaupenjo for guidance. I've created 1 item and 1 creative tab and they both do in fact appear in the game when I run the test client; however I encountered bugs such as the item being untextured and the tab still having the directory name rather than the name I established for it in the language file (en_us).

After some examination of my code I found silly errors relating to the item's model file (the refined_emerald.json) turns out I forgot how to write in json for a minute their and accidentally put it like this `"parent:item/generated"` instead of putting it like this `"parent" : "item/generated"`. The second bug related to the model file was that it was called refined_emeral.json instead of refined_emerald.json. So after changing those and then discovering that I forgot to put the name for the creative mode tab in the language file, after fixing that I ran the test client.

Well as it turns out the test client never actually loaded my changes and is stuck before I changed anything. It there something that I should do after every change is made before running the client that I'm not aware of? Like changing the version number? (I just started development yesterday)

For all reference here is a link to the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/In0ctScuirrle/Scuirrles-Starforge-1.20.1

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there was a tiny simple mistake in the model file. For those of you who encounter a similar error make DOUBLY SURE that when you define your item texture you put this:

{
"parent" : "item/generated",
"**textures**" : {
"layer0" : "starforgery:item/pure_emerald"
}
}

And not this:

{
"parent" : "item/generated",
"**texture**" : {
"layer0" : "starforgery:item/pure_emerald"
}
}

I've bolded the error, check your typos people! Happy coding!